# dialogContext.activeDialog always undefined when using waterfall dialog

Tags: typescript, dialog, botframework, state-management

I don't know why the `activeDialog` field of the dialogContext is always undefined. I need to use it to see if the user is in the middle of a waterfall dialog. Here is what my bot code looks like (in typescript):

```
export class MyBot{
    constructor(){
        this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty("dialog-state");
        this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);
        this.dialogs.add(new ChoicePrompt("choice-prompt"));

        const steps = [
            step => step.prompt("choice-prompt", "What browser are you currently using?", ["!", "1"]),
            step => step.prompt("choice-prompt", "And what device are you using?", "!", "1")
        ];

        this.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog("something", steps));
    }

    public async onTurn(context: TurnContext) {
        const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);
        console.log(dc.activeDialog); // always logs undefined
        return dc.beginDialog("something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the state of the conversation at the end of the turn otherwise the dialog state will start anew on every turn. Try adding this to the (or near the) end of your `onTurn` method:

```typescript
this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
```

Also, I would point out that there's no point in return the result of the `dc.beginDialog` call from the `onTurn` method because `onTurn` is technically not expected to return any value.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that in the sample docs. Thanks! And thanks for the return advice!

Comment: I've also found this to be useful in Startup to ensure state is saved at the end of every turn automatically without having to think about it : `options.Middleware.Add(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(userState, conversationState));`

Comment: @Leeroy yes, that middleware is useful for that, but has a major drawback which is that you cannot resolve an optimistic concurrency conflicts yourself... it will just fail, the user will get an error (based on whatever you do in `OnTurnError` handler) and it will be like the turn never happened from a state perspective.